# Deploy eureka server in PCF : Getting 404 after cf push to Cloud foundry

Tags: spring

My manifest.yml file is as follows

`---
   applications:
   - name: eureka-test-service
   memory: 1024M
   instances: 1
   host: eureka-test-service
   path: target/test-eureka-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
   buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack
   env:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE : cloud`

And my application.properties

```
`server.port=8761
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/`
```

When I push the Eureka server to PCF via cf push , I get the app running successfully with URL in the space in PCF . But on hitting the URL I get a XML and https:/eureka gives 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I gave the proper property

```
eureka.instance.hostname=${vcap.application.uris[0]}
eureka.instance.non-secure-port=80
eureka.instance.metadata-map.instanceId=${vcap.application.instance_id}
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds = 5
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds = 5
#eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${vcap.services.eureka-service.credentials.uri}/eureka/
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=${vcap.services.eureka-service.credentials.uri:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/
```

This link https://github.com/making/cf-eureka-server is helpful!